# Android logcat message (E/SMD: DCD on)

Tags: android, camera, logcat, galaxy

I'm now trying to record images at approximately 10Hz on a Samsung Galaxy SIII phone using the android SDK, but my program always suffers from large delays regularly. When I looked at the logcat, I found the following message associated with every time delay:

03-05 20:20:07.875: E/SMD(196): DCD ON

Could someone tell me what this message stand for? and how can I disable it?

Comment: could you please post the complete logs. I suspect some out of memory issue here, but not for sure.

Comment: Hi. Did you managed to find the problem ? Many thanks man!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android phone "DCD ON" error, constantly running in Logcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292177/android-phone-dcd-on-error-constantly-running-in-logcat)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the message `E/SMD﹕ DCD ON` is a part of inter process communication which is issued by SMD port due to DCD (data carrier detect), when the phone is searching for a mobile network to connect to. It only seems to happen on Qualcomm chipsets.

This message is probably not coming from your app.