# Android phone "DCD ON" error, constantly running in Logcat

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-logcat

I am trying to run and test my app, but in my `LogCat` (besides the usual stacktrace from my app), I get all this weird extra red errors, and have no idea what it is from. It is frustrating because it keeps adding more lines, when I am just trying to find my app errors, so it's hard to scroll to find my app errors. Even when I am not pressing anything on my phone, it keeps adding these weird `DCD ON` lines and more... Any idea how to stop them from being my LogCat? I am using a Samsung Galaxy 5. Thanks.

**LogCat**

```
02-02 20:01:17.245      264-749/? E/AudioResampler﹕ Unsupported sample format, 1 bits, 1 channels
02-02 20:01:17.255     264-7385/? E/AudioSink﹕ received unknown event type: 1 inside CallbackWrapper !
02-02 20:01:17.535     763-7387/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
02-02 20:01:18.185     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21626
02-02 20:01:18.285      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:21.295      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/QSEECOMAPI:﹕ Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/TZ: qc_tlc_communication﹕ QSEECom_start_app failed: path = /firmware/image, fname = tima_pkm
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/TZ: qc_tlc_communication﹕ max_sendmsg_size = 262208, max_recvmsg_size = 262208, ret = 0xffffffff
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/QSEECOMAPI:﹕ Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/TZ: qc_tlc_communication﹕ QSEECom_start_app failed: path = /firmware/image, fname = tima_pkm
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/TZ: qc_tlc_communication﹕ max_sendmsg_size = 262208, max_recvmsg_size = 262208, ret = 0xffffffff
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/QSEECOMAPI:﹕ Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/TZ: qc_tlc_communication﹕ QSEECom_start_app failed: path = /firmware/image, fname = tima_pkm
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/TZ: qc_tlc_communication﹕ max_sendmsg_size = 262208, max_recvmsg_size = 262208, ret = 0xffffffff
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/QSEECOMAPI:﹕ Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/TZ: qc_tlc_communication﹕ QSEECom_start_app failed: path = /firmware/image, fname = tima_pkm
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/TZ: qc_tlc_communication﹕ max_sendmsg_size = 262208, max_recvmsg_size = 262208, ret = 0xffffffff
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/QSEECOMAPI:﹕ Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/TZ: qc_tlc_communication﹕ QSEECom_start_app failed: path = /firmware/image, fname = tima_pkm
02-02 20:01:21.805    7438-7438/? E/TZ: qc_tlc_communication﹕ max_sendmsg_size = 262208, max_recvmsg_size = 262208, ret = 0xffffffff
02-02 20:01:23.055     763-1092/? E/lights﹕ write_int failed to open -1
02-02 20:01:24.295      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:27.295      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:30.295      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:33.295      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:36.295      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:39.295      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:42.295      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:45.305      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:48.195     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21627
02-02 20:01:48.305      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:51.305      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:54.305      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:01:57.305      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:00.305      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:03.305      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:06.305      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:09.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:12.305      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:15.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:18.195     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21628
02-02 20:02:18.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:21.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:24.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:27.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:30.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:33.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:36.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:39.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:42.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:45.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:48.185     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21629
02-02 20:02:48.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:51.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:54.315      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:57.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:02:58.045     763-1043/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ Error! unhandled message{ when=-3ms what=135188 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
02-02 20:02:58.315      763-763/? E/LocSvc_flp﹕ I/===> int flp_inject_location(FlpLocation*) line 194
02-02 20:02:58.315      763-763/? E/LocSvc_utils_q﹕ D/msg_q_snd: Sending message with handle = 0x7F8AE188
02-02 20:02:58.315      763-763/? E/LocSvc_utils_ll﹕ D/linked_list_add: Adding to list data_obj = 0x7F8AE188
02-02 20:02:58.315     763-1253/? E/LocSvc_utils_q﹕ D/msg_q_rcv: Received message 0x7F8AE188 rv = 0
02-02 20:02:58.315     763-1253/? E/LocSvc_api_v02﹕ I/---> locClientSendReq line 2332 QMI_LOC_INJECT_POSITION_REQ_V02
02-02 20:02:58.325      763-763/? E/LocSvc_utils_q﹕ D/msg_q_snd: Finished Sending message with handle = 0x7F8AE188
02-02 20:02:58.325     763-1969/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalRespCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientRespIndUnionType, void*) line 113 QMI_LOC_INJECT_POSITION_REQ_V02
02-02 20:02:58.335     763-1253/? E/LocSvc_api_v02﹕ D/loc_free_slot:299]: freeing slot 0
02-02 20:03:00.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:03.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:06.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:09.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:12.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:15.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:18.195     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21630
02-02 20:03:18.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:21.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:24.325      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:27.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:30.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:33.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:36.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:39.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:42.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:45.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:48.195     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21631
02-02 20:03:48.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:51.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:54.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:03:57.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:00.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:03.345      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:06.335      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:09.345      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:12.345      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:15.345      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:18.195     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21632
02-02 20:04:18.345      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:21.345      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:24.345      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:27.345      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:30.345      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:33.345      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:36.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:39.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:42.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:45.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:48.195     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21633
02-02 20:04:48.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:51.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:54.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:04:57.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:00.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:03.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:06.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:09.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:12.355      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:15.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:18.195     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21634
02-02 20:05:18.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:21.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:24.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:27.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:30.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:33.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:35.575     763-1092/? E/lights﹕ write_int failed to open -1
02-02 20:05:35.575      763-989/? E/PersonaManagerService﹕ Unable to read user list
02-02 20:05:35.675      763-965/? E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-02 20:05:35.745     763-1020/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-02 20:05:35.745     763-1020/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-02 20:05:35.805      763-964/? E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
02-02 20:05:35.815    7635-7635/org.azurespot E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
02-02 20:05:35.815    7635-7635/org.azurespot E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> org.azurespot [ userId:0 | appId:10252 ]
02-02 20:05:36.015    7635-7635/org.azurespot E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
02-02 20:05:36.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:39.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:41.585     763-1092/? E/lights﹕ write_int failed to open -1
02-02 20:05:42.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:45.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:48.195     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21635
02-02 20:05:48.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:51.365      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:54.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:05:57.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:00.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:03.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:06.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:09.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:12.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:15.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:18.205     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21636
02-02 20:06:18.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:21.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:24.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:27.375      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:30.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:30.925    7707-7707/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
02-02 20:06:30.925    7707-7707/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.sec.spp.push:RemoteDlcProcess [ userId:0 | appId:10041 ]
02-02 20:06:31.395   9257-11405/? E/SPPClientService﹕ [b] __PingReply__
02-02 20:06:31.465    7707-7707/? E/SPPClientService﹕ ============PushLog. commonIsShipBuild. stop!
02-02 20:06:31.465    7707-7707/? E/SPPClientService﹕ [PushClientApplication] Push log off : This is Ship build version
02-02 20:06:33.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:36.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:39.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:42.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:45.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:48.205     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21637
02-02 20:06:48.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:51.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:54.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:06:57.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:00.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:03.385      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:06.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:09.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:12.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:15.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:18.205     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21638
02-02 20:07:18.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:21.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:24.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:27.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:30.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:33.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:36.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:39.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:42.395      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:43.135     763-1043/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ Error! unhandled message{ when=-1ms what=135188 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
02-02 20:07:43.355      763-763/? E/LocSvc_flp﹕ I/===> int flp_inject_location(FlpLocation*) line 194
02-02 20:07:43.365      763-763/? E/LocSvc_utils_q﹕ D/msg_q_snd: Sending message with handle = 0x80EBC410
02-02 20:07:43.365      763-763/? E/LocSvc_utils_ll﹕ D/linked_list_add: Adding to list data_obj = 0x80EBC410
02-02 20:07:43.365     763-1253/? E/LocSvc_utils_q﹕ D/msg_q_rcv: Received message 0x80EBC410 rv = 0
02-02 20:07:43.365     763-1253/? E/LocSvc_api_v02﹕ I/---> locClientSendReq line 2332 QMI_LOC_INJECT_POSITION_REQ_V02
02-02 20:07:43.365      763-763/? E/LocSvc_utils_q﹕ D/msg_q_snd: Finished Sending message with handle = 0x80EBC410
02-02 20:07:43.365     763-1969/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalRespCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientRespIndUnionType, void*) line 113 QMI_LOC_INJECT_POSITION_REQ_V02
02-02 20:07:43.375     763-1253/? E/LocSvc_api_v02﹕ D/loc_free_slot:299]: freeing slot 0
02-02 20:07:45.405      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:48.205     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21639
02-02 20:07:48.405      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:51.405      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:54.405      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:07:57.405      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:00.405      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:03.405      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:06.405      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:09.405      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:12.415      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:15.415      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:18.205     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21640
02-02 20:08:18.405      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:21.415      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:24.415      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:27.415      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:30.415      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:33.415      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:36.415      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:39.415      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:42.415      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:45.415      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:48.205     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21641
02-02 20:08:48.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:51.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:54.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:08:57.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:00.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:03.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:06.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:09.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:12.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:15.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:18.205     763-1211/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 21642
02-02 20:09:18.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:21.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:24.425      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:27.435      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:30.435      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:33.435      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
02-02 20:09:36.435      255-255/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
```

Answer (score 2):

I hate it when tools don't do what you need them to do. I struggled for a long time with issues just like you are having. Originally I tried using the command-line and chaining grep's together but it seems you can only chain a few before you loose all your output. I wasted so much time on that.

DCD ON is produced by `/system/bin/smdexe`. You could try to filter out the PID that smdexe is running on.

If you are on a Mac I think your best bet is to use LogRabbit (I am the creator of the tool so of course I am biased).

View only your messages in LogRabbit by starting the logger and then right click on your applications name. Select "Add Filter...". Save the filter and select from the list. Now you will see only your apps data. You can do a lot more but that is a great starting point.

Here are some tutorials of what you can do: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeildKynnuc&list=PLZVr2R6DumNZUoMZRndqM7cL63gp2NTYE

I hope this helps you.

By the way this is an animated GIF that I think explains what scroll lock is like for logcat in Android Studio and Eclipse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3y2Q.jpg

Answer (score 1):

To getting things done (see "To get all logs from your application only") you have to filter logcat output by tag or by package name:

```
tag:MyTag
```

or

```
app:com.myapplicationpackage
```

**Edit:** If you want to get all logcat errors and first filtering solution doesn't sound suitable to you, You can still get rid of the problem by printing logcat in terminal with excluded "DCD ON" error lines:

```
adb logcat *:E | grep -v "DCD ON"
```

or

```
adb logcat | grep -e "E/" | grep -v "DCD ON"
```

**Update (about "DCD ON"):**
It seems message `E/SMD﹕ DCD ON` is a part of inter process communication which is issued by SMD port due to DCD (data carrier detect) online status. For more precise information you can contact [Qualcomm Developers Forum](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum).

Comment: I did try the filter, by choosing only my application package, but then nothing at all shows in the `LogCat`. I don't know why, it should show. I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Oh wait, I looked into the package name it had... when I had refactored, my package name (a long time ago), it did not change it in the `LogCat` filter! My goodness, who would have have ever guessed. Well, you didn't solve the entire problem, but you pointed me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: @NoniA. You're welcom, pal! Can you accept my answer?

Comment: It was only part of the problem (the refactoring mistake was the other part), so I think I should not do that. But I did give you an up vote. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**On Mac**

Quit `Android Studio` and run it again.  That fixed my issue.